# Does all computer science research involve heavy usage of mathematics?

Tags: career-path, computer-science, early-career, methodology

I am starting my graduate studies in computer science this year and am confused as to what quality research (some new innovation or discovery) domain I would choose specifically amongst virtualization, distributed computing, containers, and/or blockchain.

My main issue is that I understand but am not interested in algorithms and their efficiencies. Similarly, I can understand my undergraduate level mathematics but that does not interest me. I have good knowledge and understanding of operating systems, virtualization, and containers concepts.

I have researched regarding this online and came to know people normally only compare out the efficiency of one algorithm over another in problems of memory sharing, process switching, and other similar problems; is there any other method or means to do something new in the field of cloud computing, containers or blockchain?

It would be quite helpful if any expert(s) from these domains could enlighten me regarding as to what type of research is currently going on in these domains and how research work in these domains can be done (while staying away from algorithms and complex mathematics).

Thanks to all those who answered and commented. Answering some comments and to give some more context to my question:

- I am looking to select my research area from the broad domains of Cloud (virtualization and administration), DevOps methodologies and tools (optimizing workflows and processes), Containers technology (for example dockers and kubernetes), and Blockchain optimization ( I am aware this one would involve complex algorithms).
- I'm not looking to write PHP scripts or JS (I know that is engineering). I personally dislike front-end scripting. Some of my projects include setting up a private cloud infrastructure for a company in an internship, writing shell scripts for CI/CD purposes and creating a custom RHEL ISO which already has preinstalled software (no, not templates). Basically, I am proficient in Python, bash shell, Java, C and have a good understanding of how OS, Cloud and IT infrastructure generally works. You can say I am interested in the data center or infrastructure optimization.

So, my question's main perspective is: I find it hard to believe that computer science research (at least development of new techniques, tools, and platforms) is impossible without deep knowledge of mathematics and algorithm designing (I may be wrong but that's the point of the question). Is there established research work or progress done in these domains that do not involve very complex usage of algorithms and mathematics like integration, differentiation and such. Please note, I am trying to avoid *complex* usage and modification of algorithms and its maths. I am interested to discover methodologies of such research (I am hardly able to find much on the Internet).

Comment: Look at relevant conferences. [USENIX](https://www.usenix.org/), [SIGOPS](https://www.sigops.org/)

Comment: Yes. Computer *science* is impossible without heavy usage of mathematics.

Comment: Removing maths from computer science would leave it as 'non-science'.

Comment: @peterh Impossible? I think thats a rather extreme position. Increasingly, cs thinks of itself in a "big tent" metaphor. I am not sure I'd agree with the assertion that cs research is "impossible" without mathematics.

Comment: @Shion I faced sometimes that under the name "cs", actually a pseudo-mathematical bulls*t is thaught, particularly for first-year undergrads. And real cs is coming later some semesters (or never). Of course my - maybe too categoric - opinion doesn't include this case. But I think the problem of the OP isn't that. I think the OP only wants to write PHP scripts, and Javascripts, and he won't understand why he doesn't get an MSc only for these.

Comment: @peterh I understand where you are coming from but what do you mean by real "cs". I'd be careful about putting boundaries around disciplines.

Comment: @Shion The problem of the OP what you can see in the picture of Oleg Lebachev's answer. On this level, there is only a single cs, this is what the OP calls as "heavy usage of Mathematics".

Comment: ParthPatel As you maybe could have read in the news, quantum computing seems to be capable to crack the currently best thought encryption systems. But 1) most currently used encryption algorithms doesn't have a mathematical proof that they are uncrackable. 2) there are encryption algorithms which are uncrackable also with quantum machines. | Do you feel it an interesting challenge, to understand how a QM-resistant, mathematically proven uncrackable algorithm could look?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks, I will take a look at those.

Comment: @peterh and Coder kindly look at my edit of the question.

Comment: It sounds like you're interested in engineering, not science. Which is fine of course. But the distinction is important...

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks for the guidance. But I am specifically looking for research or coursework done by people in the systems side of aforementioned fields so that I can get a more clear picture of what and *how* I need to do it.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo CS is composed of multiple, heavily-overlapping subfields, of which “theory” and ”systems” are only two (or more accurately, about seven and a half).

Comment: While there are  some areas of CS (and especially software engineering) that don't require a lot of math, none of the ones you mention have that characteristic. If you want to study "cloud" then you will be studying efficiency (and scalability) pretty intensely.

Comment: Sounds like you're more interested in software system engineering or system architecture than computer science. Consider going straight for AWS or Azure training. I think a lot of folks get twisted up over computers and computer science. Long long time ago there were serious discussions about this field being neither about computers nor a science. Big names you might recognize.

Comment: @Aruralreader that's correct. I asked this question when I was just starting my master's and did not know much about the difference between Computer science and engineering. I am currently working as an SRE/Systems Administrator, but am more interested in distributed systems programming.

Answer (score 9):

The sad truth is that you absolutely don't need CS for most practical programming tasks.

But without a CS degree, you will have nearly zero chance for the better programming jobs.

Furthermore, without a high-level math/cs knowledge, your mental skills remain significantly under-developed, compared to your own possibilities or to the ones who actually got this degree.

The sad truth is, that the job of a programmer, *the ability to write a program what a customer pays for*, is hard, but it is an absolutely different type of knowledge, like to know the math of the General Relativity. This truth is so sad, so catastrophal, that you will likely spent some decades of your life, whining on it. But it is the truth.

*CS*, its math, yes it is such a knowledge. For example, to understand, *why there is no such thing as "best compressor"* (more exactly: there is, but there is no program what could implement it), is a similarly complex and interesting knowledge, like cutting edge physics. But you absolutely don't need this skill to be a well-going programmer selecting freely between well-paying jobs.

This is how the world works. You can fight it, you can whine on it. I did both of them, decades long.... *and I never became a scientist, only a programmer*.

These fights and these tears are yet before you.

My advice would be this: *learn that math, and get your degree*. So:

- you will fight
- you will whine
- you won't ever use it
- and you won't be ever a scientist.

But

- you will be a better man
- you will be a smarter man
- you will be able to choose freely between well-paying programmer jobs.

Believe me: if you do this *now*, you will be pride for that in your *whole life*. Despite the lifelong pain of your never reached goals.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to say. I appreciate you sharing your experience regarding this. I am also attempting to do the same, I want to contribute something new to the field of computer science and do some meaningful research in it, but even if I fail in doing that, I know I will be left with more in-depth knowledge of the domain and computer science in general which will be certainly beneficial in future. Again, thanks for sharing your honest experience and opinion.

Comment: I disagree with this answer.

Comment: @Kevin Would you share the reason with me?

Comment: Sure. I got my terminal master's in CS and didn't like being in academia, so I went right into industry programming. I could do the work I do now without having a solid knowledge of theory, but I do see how it makes me a much better programmer. It: Helps me design patterns for some more challenging pieces of code. Allows me to make smart decisions in situations where performance and algorithmic complexity matter. Lets me understand exactly how the compiler parses my code, keeping trickier expressions from tripping me up...

Comment: And makes it easier to understand what's going on when concepts like recursion and working with trees some up directly, like working with browser DOMs or Git histories. Altogether, having a CS background isn't necessary to being an industry programmer, but I do use what I learned in CS every day on my job, and I'm able to write significantly better code as a result.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I agree that CS knowledge improves the code quality and the learning performance. My examples are wonderful and very deep things, which are totally unused in the "industrial" IT. Btw, I think the overwhelming majority of the professional programmers I know, would be totally incapable to implement a simple AVL-tree. And I see absolutely no correlation between their this skill, and their actual success (measured in boss/customer satisfication).

Comment: @Kevin Most of the professional programmers have simply no idea, how most encryption algorithms work. Not even the ones having CS degree. They once learned it, passed an exam from it, and then they forgot it. Now they have some blurry remembers from the main concepts, that is all. They typically know the encryption API of their most known language/framework, and that it all. Saying them that it is not okay, would be likely counted as a hard insult.

Comment: Even a high school student can do programming, and there are many good ones out there. But if you want to become a computer scientist who can design and implement complicated systems, you need the mathematics.

Comment: @Damodar The OP doesn't want to be a computer scientist. Next time read the post before you vote.

Answer (score 7):

About me: I am a mathematician with a PhD in CS. Now, to your question:

Basically,

## Yes

There are fields of CS that are less inclined to mathematics, such as "informatics and society". There is at least one field in CS that lives between mathematics, CS, and philosophy of all sciences! Logical programming, that is.

But as a computer scientist, you would need some amount of undergraduate level mathematics. Big-O analysis? Math! DACs? Math! Heck, moving a camera around in your 3D game is more math than many are comfortable with.

(I kid you not, I routinely thought about a camera path for a very simple 3D scene in spherical coordinates today, with code and such, fully convenient and natural. And then it occurred to me that spherical coordinates used to be a big deal during high school.)

And don't get me started on mathematical software or formal languages.

As some claim, informatics is a portmanteau of "information" and "mathematics".

[image]
http://abstrusegoose.com/206

Comment: I know Oleg, while developing any new product or technique in computer science there is more math involved than desired by many. You can take a look at my edit to the question. After looking some more, I think I am interested more in data center (or in general IT infrastructure) optimization with the use of cloud, virtualization, containers, and/or blockchain. I am looking to do my research in those areas and would appreciate any guidance in these areas.

Answer (score 5):

> I find it hard to believe that computer science research (at least development of new techniques, tools, and platforms) is impossible without deep knowledge of mathematics and algorithm designing

It is true that CS research requires some knowledge of mathematics and algorithm design.

However, it is debatable that such knowledge is *deep* knowledge. It could be superficial in some aspects.

Some professional mathematicians -think of University professors or, in France, [CNRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centre_national_de_la_recherche_scientifique) researchers in math- might (jokingly) say that CS is for those who have not been able to assess *deeply* mathematical knowledge.

I've got a PhD in CS, and the math I have used is much simpler that some algebraic topology lectures that I tried to follow in my Master's (I failed the exam on these lectures).

IIRC, D.Knuth said once that computer science is the mathematics of resources.

As other answers explain, you do need some mathematics to do computer science. (but you probably need less math than a professional mathematician do).

In some comment, you add:

> I think I am interested more in data center (or in general IT infrastructure) optimization with the use of cloud, virtualization, containers, and/or blockchain.

Then you still need to learn and use a lot of math (any kind of optimization work involves some math). But it is not as heavy as you say.

<sup>(so I tend to call "shallow knowledge of mathematics" what you describe as "deep knowledge of mathematics" and what is needed in computer science)</sup>

However, you probably need a few thousand hours of training in math to do CS (I don't call that deep knowledge).

<sup>(so you don't imagine how heavy is the knowledge of professional mathematicians)</sup>

Be sure to read http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: Thank you Basile Starynkevitch. I had an intuition that what I am aiming forward does not require much mathematical knowledge and complexity. But your statement - "the math I have used is much simpler that some algebraic topology lectures that I tried to follow in my Master's" is what strengthens my intuition. I am looking forward for some concrete proofs and especially methods of doing that. Almost every paper I open is just based on an algorithm's efficiency, and a majority of cloud papers include the comparison of workload tasks on various platforms.

Comment: The point is that you don't define what is "deep knowledge of mathematics". I am French and was educated in France. I feel that what I learned in [CPGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classe_pr%C3%A9paratoire_aux_grandes_%C3%A9coles) -read that wikipage, it is very specific to France- is not deep math (but shallow), but is essential for computer science. So you need several thousand hours of training in math.

Comment: As I'm in my undergrad, I don't know the normal level of mathematical and algorithmic knowledge is required at research level but I can describe what I consider as complex mathematics - the neural nets, dimensionality reduction and machine learning algos.

Comment: These are not math, but specialized CS topics. And the math knowledge remains *shallow* in them, certainly not deep (or complex).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your inputs Basile Starynkevitch. Appreciate it.

Comment: Upvote for "computer science is the mathematics of resources".

Answer (score 3):

You can try a PhD in Evolutionary Computation. These folks do a lot of work with hardly any Math. Look for papers in IEEE Transactions on Evolutionary Computation. You will find a lot of papers which you can read like a novel. But if you want to seriously do some work, Math is important and you must start to like it.

Even if you want to make a serious effort toward developing something using CS tools, without Math you can never be sure that what you are doing is right. It will take time to learn it and if you stop learning it for some time or take a break you might start forgetting it.

Comment: Damodar, I am currently in my undergrad's final semester and looking forward to pursuing masters in computer science. Thanks for introducing me to the new domain of Evolutionary Computation. I will definitely look into it. I know I cannot avoid maths but I am just trying to avoid its much-complicated part.

Comment: @ParthPatel You can look into Evolutionary computation but because of lack of mathematics EC is a 'hobby technology'. Nobody uses it in industry. So you see, Math is important if you want to seriously use CS for developing something useful or solving a problem 'correctly'